# VFP how to work with two forms Concurrently

Tags: forms, visual-foxpro

in Visual Foxpro, I need to work with two forms concurrently.  When I invoke the second form, from the first form, I need the second form to stay open, when I do some work on the original form.  Presently the second form closes immediately, if I should try to click on any element in the first form.

The way I call the second form is this:

```
DO FORM imagez WITH ThisForm.pf1.page4.image7, this_form 
READ EVENTS
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

The form properties of both forms are:

DeskTop    = .T.
ShowWindow = 2 - As Top-Level-Form

Answer (score 2):

My above solution works.  I had a `ThisForm.Release()` command installed in the LostFocus event...

My apologies to all...

Dennis

Comment: That may be true, but just an FYI, running multiple forms simultaneously, you may want to look into the "FormSet" class which is like a container that holds other forms.  Again, just an FYI.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend against using FormSets. Short version why: they're kind of half-baked. Long version why: the second Q&A in http://www.tomorrowssolutionsllc.com/Articles/Changing%20all%20Forms%20in%20an%20Application.PDF